# Rails form_authenticity_token returns nothing session[:_csrf_token] returns the actual token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Long story short, im using this manually because im having to create the form in pure html.

Im using a partial (in haml)

```
%input{name: "authenticity_token", type: "hidden", value: form_authenticity_token}
```

This outputs a blank input box:

```
<input name='authenticity_token' type='hidden'>
```

But this works correctly:

```
%input{name: "authenticity_token", type: "hidden", value: session[:_csrf_token]}
```

Odd thing is, i got this from the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/form_authenticity_token)

Does anyone have any idea whats happening?

Comment: I think - but not sure - that the docs implies that `form_authenticity_token()` is only accessible in the Controller.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it works in the controller but not in the view. Can you post this as answer please. @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the docs you quoted implies that this method, `form_authenticity_token()` is only accessible in the Controllers (class: **ActionController**::RequestForgeryProtection).

You should use the `session[:_csrf_token]` directly OR you could set a shared variable:

```
# in controller
def my_action
  @auth_token_form = form_authenticity_token
end

# in view
%input{name: "authenticity_token", type: "hidden", value: @auth_token_form}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `session[:_csrf_token]`